# JPA 2 level 2 cache vs cache in ejb 3 singleton

Tags: caching, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.0

Is that wise in a JSF EJB3 JPA2 project use an EJB 3 singleton and cache
based information in EJB3 level instead of using JPA2 Level2 cache
in EJB 3 singleton we will put all read methods in a singleton EJB for example

```
public Collection<Unit> findAllUnits() {
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Unit e");
    return (Collection<Unit>) query.getResultList();
}
```

What we require to gain is some kind of application level caching mechanism 
for our base information tables.
Can some body compare this 2 ways? or any other option/suggestion?
Application server is Weblogic 11g

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its always best to utilize a second level cache rather than using Singletons and cache the data manually when the instance of the bean is being created by the container. Normally, any application of any level definitely have multiple areas where caching is required unless you have something which has very small data and is of non-complex nature. If you have large chunks, why re-invent the wheel as current day solution are sophisticated enough to handle, Time to Live, Time to Idle, eviction strategies and even its a normal thing to control how many objects one wants to have in the cache.

In short, use any second level cache solution unless you have very straight forward and simplest of requirements in your application.